# What is the expression to say that you have started to think about a topic extensively?

Tags: word-request

What is the term when you start to think about something extensively e.g. you think about the answer to a question or you think like where to go for your next trip? I want to emphasize the importance of the thing that I am thinking/contemplating/pondering, it's important that I don't think about anything else until I figure out the answer or make the decision.

Please also suggest the informal expression of expressing such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

One word is

> **engross**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> Absorb all the attention or interest of.

An example usage is

> I am engrossed in finding the answer to your question.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/engross). Also there are synonyms such as *immerse* and *preoccupy*.

An informal expression could be

> I have thrown myself into solving this problem.